# A quicker way to update lots of values

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

Im updating many fields using ajax. My server is getting a row from the database then I am JSON encoding the row and sending this as my xmlhttp.responseText.

The response text is of the form

```
 {"JobCardNum":5063,"IssueTo":"MachineShop","Priority":"High" ...lots of data}
```

In the browser I then JSON parse the response text and then begin the long process of updating the values like so:

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(info);
            document.getElementById("JobCardNum").value = obj.JobCardNum;
            document.getElementById("IssueTo").value = obj.IssueTo;
            document.getElementById("MachineShop").value = obj.MachineShop; 
....... lots of similar statements
```

As the element id matches the column names I though there might be a way to loop through my JavaScript object and set all my values. Any Ideas?

Comment: Are u looking for a way to loop javascript object? [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object) may be of some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `Object.keys` and `Array.forEach` functions:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(info);

Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(id){
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    if (el) el.value = obj[id];
});
```

Comment: Is there an equivalent of this for php, i.e after retiring a row from a database can we then set aload of variables, named with the names of the columns

Comment: if it's about PHP: create new question with `php` tag and let me know, I'll help

Answer (score 2):

This code should iterate over your json object and update the values.

```
for (var key in p) {
  if (p.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var el = document.getElementById(key);
    if(el) el.value = p[key];
  }
}
```

Comment: Just for safechecking, we should check if the element exists first, but it was almost the same code I was about to post. :)

Comment: Im getting this:
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementById(key).value = p[key]')

Comment: And its only updating the first value